# Finding generators of cubic Kummer extensions

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a number field containing $\mu_3$, the third roots of unity. Consider a monic irreducible cubic polynomial $f \in K[x]$ whose discriminant $\Delta$ is a square in $K$. Thus the splitting field $L$ of $f$ gives a $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$-extension of $K$, and by Kummer Theory, we have

$$ L = K(\sqrt[3]{a})$$

for some non-cube $a \in K$. I would like to know how to find such an $a$.

Perhaps more concretely, the splitting field of $f = x^3 + Ax + B$ (say) is equal to the splitting field of an irreducible cubic of the form $x^3 - a$ (by Kummer Theory), and I guess I'm asking, how do I go from $x^3 + Ax + B$ to $x^3 - a$?

Answer (score 5):

Kummer theory says that since the norm of an n-th root of unity $\zeta$ is $1$, Hilbert 90 gives an element $\alpha \in L$ with $\sigma(\alpha) = \zeta \alpha$, where $\sigma$ generates the Galois group. Then $a = \alpha^3$.

Now the proof of Hilbert 90 is constructive, so there seem to be no problems.

Comment: I see, so if $t_1, t_2, t_3$ are the roots of my given $f$, then a choice for $\alpha$ from Hilbert 90 is $t_1 + \zeta t_2 + \zeta^2 t_3$? Thank you Franz.

Comment: Making this more explicit $(t_1 + \zeta t_2 + \zeta^2 t_3)^3 = m_3 - (3/2) m_{21} + 6 m_{111} + (3/2) \sqrt{-3} \Delta$ where the $m_{\lambda}$ are the monomial symmetric functions in the $t_i$. You should be able to rewrite this as an explicit formula in terms of $A$, $B$ and $\Delta$.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this so I worked everything out explicitly in a slightly more general setting then the original question. See the other answer for a motivation for this computation.

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $>3$ with $\zeta_3 \in K$ and $L$ be a cubic extension with Galois group $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. Suppose $f= x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is a polynomial defining this cubic extension and that $t_1, t_2$ and $t_3$ are the roots of $f$ in $L$. Then we know that $\Delta$ is a square in $K$, so let $\Delta^{1/2} := (t_3-t_2)(t_3-t_1)(t_2-t_1)$ denote a specific choice of square root of $\Delta$ depending on an ordering of the roots of $f$. Finally let $$s := (t_1+t_2\zeta_3+t_3\zeta_3^2)^3=3\frac{\zeta_3^2-\zeta_3} 2\Delta^{1/2} - a^3 + \frac 9 2ab - \frac {27} 2c.$$
Then $x^3-s$ is also a defining polynomial for the field extension $L/K$ because $L = K(t_1+t_2\zeta_3+t_3\zeta_3^2)$.

Note that similarly one has that
$$s' := (t_1+t_3\zeta_3+t_2\zeta_3^2)^3=3\frac{\zeta_3^2-\zeta_3} 2(-\Delta^{1/2}) - a^3 + \frac 9 2ab - \frac {27} 2c.$$ is also such that $x^3-s'$ is a defining polynomial for the field extension $L/K$. Showing that it doesn't really matter which square root of $\Delta$ we pick.

Additionally, since $r := (t_1+t_2\zeta_3+t_3\zeta_3^2)(t_1+t_3\zeta_3+t_2\zeta_3^2) \in K$ and $ss'=r^3$ it is clear that $s$ and $s'$ generate the same subgroup of $K^*/(K^*)^3$.